# WCF binding over HTTPS an security at message level

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have a WCF Service over HTTP with the following binding:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RegistreReferenciaBinding">
        <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

A third party service is connecting to this Service and now this third party is requiring an HTTPS connection.

The problem is that I need to maintain the security at message level in order to be compatible with the third party Service.

To resume the situation what I need to do is configure the service to be HTTPS compatible, without client certificate while maintaining the security at message level.

What is the configuration needed to get this Service working with the same configuration but over HTTPS?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use the following configuration:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RegistreReferenciaBinding">
        <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

But with this configuration the third party Service could not connect because there was no security at message level.

From what I viewed in captured messages with Wireshark, the third party Service is using SOAP 1

The error message with this configuration was:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<s:Fault>
<faultcode>s:MustUnderstand</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="es-ES">El destinatario de este mensaje no entendió el encabezado 'Security' del espacio de nombres 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd', por lo que el mensaje no se procesó. Este error suele indicar que el remitente del mensaje habilitó un protocolo de comunicación que el destinatario no puede procesar. Asegúrese de que la configuración del enlace del cliente es coherente con el enlace del servicio. </faultstring>
</s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I also tried with the following configuration:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RegistreReferenciaBinding">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredentials">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

And it failed again.

Comment: What did you try and what problems did arise?

Comment: I've updated the post with more information as requested by @nvoigt

Comment: What about "TransportWithMessageCredential"?

Comment: I tried that too, but It also failed. the configuration I used is on the second update

Comment: Do you have more information than "it failed"? Maybe an error message?

Comment: I need the third party to make the connection test to get the message. I will ask for the error message and post it here as soon as I can. thanks for the help.